# Why is a formula for centroid of polygon not working for triangle?

Tags: geometry, centroid

I have a situation where I have to calculate the centroid of arbitrary polygons, the coordinates of whose vertices are given. The polygons can be triangles, quadrilaterals or pentagons. The only thing I know in advance is that they are all convex and non-self-intersecting.

After a lot of searching (on the internet), I decided to settle on the formula that Wikipedia provides.

[image]

When I tried to apply this formula for a triangle, the centroid it found sometimes tended to lie outside the triangle, and it never equaled the coordinates of the centroid I found by averaging the vertices of the triangle.

It is true that I don't know enough about the formula itself and could not understand it better after I looked up the reference Wikipedia supplied. Are there some assumptions that would make the formula inapplicable for the case of a triangle? Or, is there something I'm doing wrong entirely and are the centroids generated for the pentagons wrong as well? As far as I have read, I only need to ensure that the vertices are ordered counter-clockwise or clockwise.

Comment: It is the same. If you throw your expressions for a triangle, say that for $C_x$, to a CAS.
$$C_x = \frac{(x_1+x_2)(x_1y_2 - x_2y_1) + (x_2+x_3)(x_2y_3 - x_3y_2) + (x_3 + x_1)(x_3y_1 - x_1y_3)}{
6\times\frac12\left((x_1y_2 - x_2y_1) + (x_2y_3 - x_3y_2) + (x_3y_1 - x_1y_3)\right)}$$ It will simplify to what you have learned before. e.g $C_x$ becomes $\displaystyle\;\frac{x_1+x_2+x_3}{3}$.

Comment: The most likely explanation for what you have seen is you copied the indices incorrectly during your calculation. It is very easy to make mistakes on that. There is a way to remember which indices go where. You use the fact the expression for $C_x, C_y$ and $A$ is invariant under cyclic permutation $1 \to 2 \to 3$. Once you write down the correct expression for the first term, you could/should generate the remaining term by cyclic permutation.

Comment: Thank you! I got it right. I was working this out in a program and turns out when I work it out by hand, it works alright. I found the programming error too. I'm sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must be making a mistake in applying the formula, because it is easy to show that the centroid comes out right for a triangle.  I will show it for $C_x$; $C_y$ is similar.

Start with (per the formula) 
$$
\frac{1}{6A} \left( (x_0+x_1)(x_0 y_1 - x_1 y_0) + (x_1+x_2)(x_1 y_2 - x_2 y_1)
+ (x_2+x_0)(x_2 y_0 - x_0 y_2) \right)
$$
Now add zero:
$$
0 = \frac{1}{6A} \left( (x_0 x_1 y_2 - x_1 x_0 y_2) + (x_1 x_2 y_0 - x_2 x_1 y_0) + (x_2 x_0 y_1 - x_0 x_2 y_1) \right)
= \frac{1}{6A} \left( x_2 (x_0 y_1 - x_1 y_0) + x_0 (x_1 y_2 - x_2 y_1) + x_1 (x_2 y_0 - x_0 y_2)  \right)
$$
and group the terms in the obvious way so that the formula becomes
$$
\frac{1}{6A} \left( (x_0+x_1+x_2)(x_0 y_1 - x_1 y_0) + (x_1+x_2+x_0)(x_1 y_2 - x_2 y_1)
+ (x_2+x_0+x_1)(x_2 y_0 - x_0 y_2) \right)
=(x_0+x_1+x_2) \frac{(x_0 y_1 - x_1 y_0) + (x_1 y_2 - x_2 y_1)
+ (x_2 y_0 - x_0 y_2)}{6A}
$$ 
and now we can insert the formula for A
$$
6A = 3  \left( (x_0 y_1 - x_1 y_0) + (x_1 y_2 - x_2 y_1)
+ (x_2 y_0 - x_0 y_2) \right)
$$
so the formula gives 
$$
C_x = \frac{1}{3}(x_0+x_1+x_2)
$$
which matches the averaging definition of the centroid.

Comment: Thank you! I worked through your proof and arrived at the same(except the second line with adding zero, which I still do not understand). And, like I've said above, I did make a mistake in programming the formula. Worked out by hand or after correcting the error in the program, I get the right answer. Thank you for taking the effort to writing up the entire proof.